# How can I use Ant's "Get Task" to fetch a whole directory full of files from a server?

Tags: ant, webdav

I have some files stored on a WebDAV share and I'd like to use Ant's [get](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) task to fetch all of the files.

I know I can fetch them all if I specify all of the filenames like this:

```
<get dest="local_destination">
  <url url="https://dav/path/file1.txt" />
  <url url="https://dav/path/file2.txt" />
  <url url="https://dav/path/file3.txt" />
</get>
```

But I'd like to avoid enumerating all files if possible, so that I can simply add more files to the WebDAV share and re-execute the task to download the additional files.

I'd like to mirror the behavior of, for example:

```
$ wget --mirror 'https://dav/path/'
```

Is that possible? I don't see any specific configuration that would allow that.